# React Error: Objects are not valid as a React child,If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i am new to the react when i have done a crud application using React and flux i got this error my codes are below,

### UserList

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import UserStore from "../../stores/UserStore";
import * as UserActions from "../../actions/UserActions";
import AddUser from "./AddUser";

$.DataTable = require("datatables.net");

class UserList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.getUsers = this.getUsers.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      users: UserStore.getAll()
    };
    this.loadUsers();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#example").DataTable({
        ordering: true
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    UserStore.on("change", this.getUsers);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    UserStore.removeListener("change", this.getUsers);
  }

  getUsers() {
    console.log(" get users called");
    this.setState({
      users: UserStore.getAll()
    });
  }

  loadUsers() {
    UserActions.getUsersList();
  }

  render() {
    const userlistitem = this.state.users.map((user, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <th scope="row">{index}</th>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.username}</td>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
        <td>{user.dob}</td>
        <td>{user.address}</td>
        <td>{user.mobile}</td>
        <td>{user.branch}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: 80,
          marginLeft: 150,
          marginRight: 150
        }}
      >
        <div className="card text-white bg-info mb-3">
          <div className="card-body">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
              <h5>User List</h5>
              <div>
                <button
                  style={{
                    marginTop: 10
                  }}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-light "
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
                >
                  Add New User
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <table id="example" className="table table-bordered  table-striped ">
          <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">User Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">DOB</th>
              <th scope="col">Address</th>
              <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
              <th scope="col">Branch</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{userlistitem}</tbody>
        </table>
        <AddUser />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserList;
```

### Add User

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import "../../css/datepicker.css";
import * as UserActions from "../../actions/UserActions";

class AddUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      branch: "",
      name: "",
      username: "",
      mobile: "",
      email: "",
      address: "",
      dob: new Date()
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handledatepickerchange = this.handledatepickerchange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }
  handledatepickerchange(event) {
    this.setState({ dob: event });
  }

  createUser = () => {
    console.log("this is:", this);
    const user = {
      branch: this.state.branch,
      name: this.state.name,
      username: this.state.username,
      mobile: this.state.mobile,
      email: this.state.email,
      address: this.state.address,
      dob: this.state.dob
    };
    UserActions.createNewUser(user);
    this.setState({
      branch: "",
      name: "",
      username: "",
      mobile: "",
      email: "",
      address: "",
      dob: new Date()
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="exampleModalCenter"
        tabIndex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">
                Add New User
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <input
                  name="name"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  aria-label="Name"
                  aria-describedby="button-addon2"
                  value={this.state.name}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <input
                  name="username"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="User Name"
                  aria-label="User Name"
                  aria-describedby="button-addon2"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <input
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  aria-label="Email"
                  aria-describedby="button-addon2"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <input
                  name="address"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Address"
                  aria-label="Address"
                  aria-describedby="button-addon2"
                  value={this.state.address}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <input
                  name="branch"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Branch"
                  aria-label="Branch"
                  aria-describedby="button-addon2"
                  value={this.state.branch}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <DatePicker
                  name="dob"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="DOB"
                  aria-label="DOB"
                  aria-describedby="button-addon2"
                  selected={this.state.dob}
                  onChange={this.handledatepickerchange}
                />
                <p
                  style={{
                    marginTop: "5px",
                    fontWeight: "200",
                    marginLeft: "10px"
                  }}
                >
                  Date of Birth(dd/mm/yyyy)
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <input
                  name="mobile"
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Mobile No."
                  aria-label="Mobile No."
                  aria-describedby="button-addon2"
                  value={this.state.mobile}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">
              <br />
              <br />
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                onClick={this.createUser}
              >
                Save
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddUser;
```

### Action

```
import dispatcher from "../dispatcher/dispatcher";
import { BASE_URL } from "../utils/AppConstants";

export function getUsersList() {
  console.log("getting the data! ");
  fetch(BASE_URL + "/users")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      result => {
        console.log("res " + result);
        dispatcher.dispatch({ type: "RECEIVE_USERS", users: result });
      },
      // Note: it's important to handle errors here instead of a catch() block so that
      // we don't swallow exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      error => {
        //  here manage error and close loading;
        console.log("getting error " + error);
      }
    );
}

export function createNewUser(user) {
  console.log("post the data!");
  fetch(BASE_URL + "/saveuser", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      result => {
        dispatcher.dispatch({ type: "CREATE_USER", newUser: user });
      },
      // Note: it's important to handle errors here instead of a catch() block so that
      // we don't swallow exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      error => {
        //  here manage error and close loading;
        console.log("getting error " + error);
      }
    );
}
```

### Store

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
import dispatcher from "../dispatcher/dispatcher";

class UserStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    dispatcher.register(this.handleActions.bind(this));
    this.users = [
      {
        branch: "19",
        name: "Javcbvcsim11",
        username: "zxcv",
        mobile: "5645654",
        email: "demo@gmail.com111",
        address: "Demo vcbvcbAddress1",
        dob: "2020-11-06T00:00:00.000+0000"
      }
    ];
  }

  createUser(newUser) {
    this.users.push(newUser);
    console.log("new  users lenght " + this.users.lenght);
    this.emit("change");
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.users;
  }
  handleActions(action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "RECEIVE_USERS": {
        this.users = action.users;
        this.emit("change");
        break;
      }
      case "CREATE_USER": {
        this.createUser(action.newUser);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

export default new UserStore();
```

I don't know what is the problem happened here.When checked in stack over flow i got that it's the problem of iterating the data. But i already did that. even though the error remain still.If any one can help it will be much appreciable.
The error thrown in setState method. i am here using flux as the architecture.The problem occures when i try to add a new user to my data.Actualyy when i add it inserting to db without any problem. the problem is when i click save button in my AddUser component it saves in to my db but after it need to show again as a table list but the error throws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem which I can see is that you're using `user.dob` directly inside a JSX element (`<td>{user.dob}</td>`). `dob` is either `new Date()` or the direct output of `react-datepicker`'s `onChange` event, both of which are objects.

Here's a dummy component which tried to render `{new Date()}`.

```js
const App = ({ text }) => <p>{text}</p>;

// Passing Date object.
ReactDOM.render(<App text={new Date()} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

This results in an error like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=31&args[]=Mon%20Jan%2021%202019%2012%3A37%3A56%20GMT%2B0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time)&args[]=) for me:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Mon Jan 21 2019 12:37:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)).

Which means you're passing an object, not a string as a child to a JSX element.

Notice how this works:

```js
const App = ({ text }) => <p>{text}</p>;

// Passing stringified Date object.
ReactDOM.render(<App text={new Date().toString()} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I pass a string as the child of the `p` JSX element. You need to do something similar and make sure no objects are passed.

Actually, since you didn't post your entire error, it's hard to say which entry is causing the error. But, `user.dob` is my best guess.

Comment: Thanks dude.That's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through objects is tricky in React. Generally you want to use `Object.entries`/`Object.values`/`Object.keys` and then `.map`. This takes the object and creates an array and then you can iterate through the object with `.map`. `.map` will not work on an object because it is an array function, so you have to turn your object into an array first. The `.map` function will allow you to iterate in React without that error:

```
 this.state = {
          branch: "",
          name: "",
          username: "",
          mobile: "",
          email: "",
          address: ""
    }

    // Not in your constructor 
    let myObj = this.state;

    Object.entries(myObj).map(item => {
       // Successfully iterates, do what you need to do in here
    })
```

Also, it's a very bad idea to use JQuery with React. React uses a virtual DOM and doesn't play well with JQuery.